# What IPA does in these complex cases

Tags: ipa, orthography

I'm trying to think of examples where the [IPA symbols](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/IPA_chart_2018.pdf) get really complex, and find phonologies with those symbols. I'm not quite there in understanding all the aspects of IPA, but I wanted to see if these examples (a) can occur, and (b), what the IPA does to handle the diacritic overload.

- `[d̪̊ʼ]` voiceless, dental, ejective consonant
- `[d̪̊̃ʼ]` voiceless, dental, nasal, ejective consonant
- `[d̪̤̊ʼ]` voiceless, dental, breathy, ejective consonant
- `[d̪̤̝̊ʼ]` voiceless, dental, breathy, raised, ejective consonant
- `[e̤̝̋̃]` toned, breathy, raised, vowel
- etc.

Basically, I'm wondering if (a) they are just ignoring these possibilities because the IPA orthography gets too messy, or (b) these combinations never occur.

Another complicated example would be:

- (1) more rounded, (2) advanced, (3) nasalized, (4) breathy, (5) raised, (6) short.

It seems to me that the IPA annotation system would break down in these cases, and so they are simply ignored.

Wondering if one could shed light on this situation, if these types of combinations do occur and if they are documented and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IPA chart only lists the atomic letters, and not the possible combinations, except that some of the letters are diacritics, meaning that they always combine with a free-standing letter so they have to include some combinations. They don't list all of the possible combinations of the ejective diacritic plus a basic consonant letter. A voiceless dental ejective would be [t̪ʼ], combining the dental and ejective diacritics with the basis non-retroflex lingual consonant letter. A rounded voiceless dental ejective would be [t̪ʷʼ] – I don't think they prescribe an order for the diacritics on the right. The problem with [d̪̊ʼ] is that the circle diacritic really represents a devoiced *d* – there is more to [d] versus [t], in English, than vocal fold vibration. Ejectives are voiceless, not voiced, so "dʼ, bʼ" is a bit of a conceptual anomaly (though it's a fine way to spell [ɓ, ɗ] if you're aiming to reduce the number of special letters in a writing system).

"Breathy ejective" describes a physical contradiction, since breathy means that the vocal folds are abducted, and ejective means that they are constricted. "Nasal ejective" is an aerodynamic impossiblity, since an ejective requires pressure buildup in the oral cavity, and making a sound nasal means that air pressure will be instantly reduced to atmospheric pressure.

There is nothing horridly wrong with [e̤̝̋̃]. Tone, nasalization, and breathiness are all contrastive properties in some language – Jalapa Mazatec has oral and nasal vowels in three phonation types (modal, breathy, creaky) – and it is a tone language. "Raised" is not (it's a "phonetic detail"), which is why you don't often see that diacritic. Similarly, more rounded and less rounded, raised and lowered, or advanced and retracted are phonetic detail properties, not basic phonological categories.

Comment: I haven't seen anywhere on Wikipedia someone using more than 1 or 2 diacritics, so wondering if these are perhaps instead found in papers. I assume so.